# Where can I buy ores in WOW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

People talk about buying mining materials for expensive prices at auction houses, but I can never seem to find any for sale.

I'm looking at **Iron Forge** auction house, and I've looked through all the categories. Where can I find some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ore that players mine and sell on the Auction House *should* be found in the **Trade Goods** / **Metal & Stone** category.

That said, I've never felt the need to do a search within a category; I just type in the name of the specific ore that I'm looking for in the search box.

It's not too unusual to not find ores; on some servers they are often bought as quickly as they get listed, while on others there may simply not be anyone farming them at any given time.

If you're really having trouble locating a specific item over a long time period, you can try asking in Trade chat, or you can set up an alert at [The Undermine Journal](https://theunderminejournal.com/); (US and EU realms only) it will send you an email or instant message within an hour of the item you're looking for being listed.

Comment: Oceanic and Latin American realms are covered in the US version of The Undermine Journal.